# UWP C# Windows Photo Properties

Tags: c#, uwp

I wanted to read the GainControl value with the help of the Windows properties Photo. Unfortunately I get no value and can not write it. What am I doing wrong?

```
            ImageProperties imageProp = await file.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();
            IDictionary<string, object> retrievedProps = await imageProp.RetrievePropertiesAsync(Utils.MetadataPolicies);

            if (retrievedProps.ContainsKey("System.Photo.GainControl"))
            {
                exif.GainControl = (double)retrievedProps["System.Photo.GainControl"];
            }
```

I do not get any value, and when writing is an exception

> "System.ArgumentException" in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
>   Value does not fall within the expected range.

Written with the denominator and numerator

Comment: Just a guess, can you try `var props = await file.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(...);` directly?

Comment: This works, just reading and writing not. Write creates the exception